# Travis-ci and bintray deployment

Tags: travis-ci, bintray

I am trying to deploy my code to bintray through travis.
The deploy part of my .travis.yml

```
  - provider: bintray
    file: bintray.json
    user: triberraar
    key:
     secure: <encrypted key>
    on:
     repo: triberraar/triber-todo-config-server
     branch: develop
    tags: true
```

And the bintray.json file:

```
{
  "package": {
    "name": "triber-todo-config-server",
    "repo": "maven",
    "vcs_url": "https://github.com/triberraar/triber-todo-config-server",
    "github_use_tag_release_notes": true,
    "licenses": [
      "MIT"
    ],
    "public_download_numbers": false,
    "public_stats": false
  },
  "version": {
  "name": "${project.version}",
  "vcs_tag": "${project.version}",
  "released": "${build.timestamp}"
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "includePattern": "triber-todo-config-server/target/(.*\.jar)",
      "uploadPattern": "be/tribersoft/triber-todo-config-server/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/$1"
    },
    {
      "includePattern": "triber-todo-config-server/pom.xml",
      "uploadPattern": "be/tribersoft/triber-todo-config-server/${project.version}/triber-todo-config-server-${project.version}.pom"
    }
  ],
 "publish": true
}
```

However when i the build runs on travis the deploy fails due to:

```
Unexpected HTTP response code 405 returned from Bintray while checking if package 'triber-todo-config-server' exists. Response message: Method Not Allowed
```

Anyone have experience with this?
You can see the travis log here: [travis build](https://travis-ci.org/triberraar/triber-todo-config-server#L3309)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems i forgot to specify the subject. This fixed it. Cryptic error though

Comment: Just a question, how do you define the "${project.version}" and similar variables?

Comment: mine is a java project, so i have maven replacing stuff during the build and then i use that file

Comment: Awesome thanks, I'll try the same thing with gradle and see how it goes.